# Shell Command Gives Error "error after : and."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, shell, cmd, command-prompt

I used :

`Shell("cmd /k type " & System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "file.exe > " & Application.ExecutablePath & ":file.exe")`

Temp Folder : `C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Local Settings\Temp\`

Command Prompt Window gives error : File not found, error after : `and`. System can't find destination path.

I think the problem is in this name : `Documents and Settings`

What should I do to bring it to life?

**P.S : File exists, it works when I use : `start` command.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extra wrapping quotes.

```
Shell("cmd /k type """ & System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "file.exe"" > " & Application.ExecutablePath & ":file.exe")
```

Spaces are delimiters in command line parameters. If you have a space in a single parameter, you need to wrap the entire parameter in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to put your path between "". something like

```
Shell("cmd /k type \"" & System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "file.exe\" > " & Application.ExecutablePath & ":file.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks, but in Vb is "" instead of \"